# C3p0 connection pooling for jpa in persistence.xml not working?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jetty, tomcat6, c3p0

I'm still getting JDBC timeouts after trying to configure c3p0 following all of the examples I could find. I'm using JPA, Hibernate, Tomcat, MySQL [AWS RDS]. Here's the snippet from persistence.xml:

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
value="jdbc:mysql://url..." />
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
<property name="connection.provider_class"  value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider"/>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="4" />
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="3000" /> 
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="100" />
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="15" />
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5" />
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="100" />
```

And the error log:

```
09:18:51.776  WARN   org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01
09:18:51.777  ERROR  org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - The last packet successfully received from the server was 38,491,585 milliseconds ago.  ...
```

Comment: Same error for me. I decided to start a bounty for that question. @Pascal Thivent 's answer didn't help, I got no logging about c3po (also loggin is enabled).

Answer (score 19):

I found the answer from this blog :
  http://blog.hpxn.net/2009/02/05/using-c3p0-and-hibernate-3/

Properties in persistence.xml were just wrong, you should spell them beginning by hibernate :

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
  version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="mypersistenceunitname">
      <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />

        <!-- Important -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class"
          value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider" />

        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="100" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="0" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="300" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="0" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="100" />
      </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And then, you will see this fabulous log appear :

```
2011-08-15 08:58:33 com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0Registry banner
INFO: Initializing c3p0-0.9.1 [built 16-January-2007 14:46:42; debug? true; trace: 10]
2011-08-15 08:58:33 com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource getPoolManager
INFO: Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.PoolBackedDataSource@f3a94e12 [     connectionPoolDataSource -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource@6297f706     ....
```

Regards,
 Stéphane (sorry for the bounty)

Comment: can you help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47011116/the-last-packet-sent-successfully-to-the-server-was-70-400-003-milliseconds-ag

Answer (score 2):

The configuration looks OK. Activate logging and make sure that C3P0 is starting with the appropriate settings.

```
2010-10-16 11:58:31,271 INFO [main] o.h.c.ConnectionProviderFactory [ConnectionProviderFactory.java:173] Initializing connection provider: org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider
...
```

Comment: Logging is activated (Indeed I use jetty, a webserver and it logs everyting). I got the very same persistence file, c3po and c3po for hibernate both are my classpath (web-inf/classes, and everything is deployed through maven). But I got no logging information about c3po.Help please