# Using Connection Pool in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, connection-pooling, persistence.xml

I hava a standalone JPA (Hibernate) - MySQL Application.

My persistence.xml looks like:

```
     <persistence-unit name="JPAProj" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
            <!-- Persistence provider -->
            <provider>
                org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence
            </provider>
          ....
          <properties>
                    <property name='hibernate.show_sql' value='true'/>
                    <property name='hibernate.format_sql' value='true'/>
                    <property name='hibernate.dialect' value='org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect'/>
                    <property name='hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto' value='update'/>

                    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
                    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/classicmodels"/>
                    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="someuser"/>
                    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
           </properties>
     </persistence-unit>
```

**I want to use a Connection Pool (say Apache DBCP) in this application, what changes do i need to make to persistence.xml?**

Comment: I assume you also have spring here?

Comment: related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944809/c3p0-connection-pooling-for-jpa-in-persistence-xml-not-working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the c3p0 connection pooling for hibernate. Check this url [C3P0 configuration](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-configure-the-c3p0-connection-pool-in-hibernate/)

Comment: Configuring Apache DBCP Connection Pool here: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-configure-dbcp-connection-pool-in-hibernate/